# How to make this graph (heat map like) which represents bat activity during the year depending on the time of night

Tags: r, graph

I'd like to make this graph on R:
Bat activity during the year regarding the time of the night. Each yellow dot is an individual. Blue curves are the sunset and sunrise during the year

This is the plot:

[image]

My excel file looks like this.

```
Date    Sunrise Sunset  Hours_after_sunset
16/08/2020  06:34   20:56   01:05
17/07/2020  05:53   21:42   01:26
11/08/2020  06:27   21:05   02:17
30/09/2020  07:42   19:20   06:45
24/04/2020  06:31   20:49   05:01
01/07/2020  05:38   21:53   04:13
18/07/2020  05:54   21:41   01:42
04/08/2020  06:17   21:18   01:47
13/08/2020  06:30   21:02   05:14
30/06/2020  05:37   21:53   01:37
15/08/2020  06:33   20:58   01:22
04/09/2020  07:03   20:17   07:25
07/09/2020  07:07   20:11   03:30
28/06/2020  05:36   21:54   02:10
01/07/2020  05:38   21:53   04:13
19/08/2020  06:39   20:50   01:32
09/04/2020  07:01   20:26   07:11
16/05/2020  05:55   21:22   01:14
17/06/2020  05:33   21:52   05:36
22/07/2020  05:59   21:36   03:00
11/08/2020  06:27   21:05   08:42
10/08/2020  06:25   21:07   02:36
08/08/2020  06:23   21:11   07:19
05/08/2020  06:18   21:16   03:33
24/08/2020  06:46   20:40   02:12
16/08/2020  06:34   20:56   04:01
24/08/2020  06:46   20:40   04:18
19/08/2020  06:39   20:50   02:27
22/08/2020  06:43   20:44   05:00
22/08/2020  06:43   20:44   01:56
17/09/2020  07:22   19:49   06:01
```

Hoping you can help me.

Comment: What does "hours after sunset" mean?  The number of hours of activity in one night?  The time activity began?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?  Plot of the data you posted, sorted by date

[image]